Using std::ios_base::pword() in a thread-safe way?
I want to use pword() to store an additional object with any stream, but in a thread-safe way, specifically to allocate exactly one instance of the object the first time around for a given stream.  Since the void* to which pword() refers isn't atomic and therefore can't use a compare-exchange function, I believe I have to employ double-checked locking with memory barriers.  Using this as a starting point, I have:
class my_obj { /* ... */ };

my_obj* get_obj_for( std::ios_base &b ) {
  static int const index = ios_base::xalloc();
  void *p = b.pword( index );
  std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_acquire );
  if ( p == nullptr ) {
    static std::mutex mutex;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ mutex };
    p = b.pword( index );
    if ( p == nullptr ) {
      p = new my_obj;
      std::atomic_thread_fence( std::memory_order_release );
      b.pword( index ) = p;
    }
  }
  return static_cast<my_obj*>( p );
}

However, in the "Using C++11 Acquire and Release Fences" example given by that article, its pointer m_instance is std::atomic. Will my above code still be thread-safe even though the void* to which pword() refers is not std::atomic? If not, is there any way to make the code thread-safe?

Why you want to do this synchronization? Why your custom manipulator will be used from multiple threads? IMO code which uses this manipulator must use stream in mutithreaded way so it should synchronize the whole stream, not just part of it.

Ok now I see you are mixing singleton logic with io manipulator logic. Split this then your code will be more clear. Note you do not have full control over pword you should not synchronize it, this is not responsibility of your manipulator.

It's a separate object (and hence manipulator) per stream. But even if the user uses, say, cout incorrectly without locks from two different threads to prevent output from getting intertwined (which is bad, but not undefined behavior), I don't want my code to add undefined behavior via a data-race to their bug.

Ok separate object per stream. But stream by default is not thread safe (only std::cout std::cerr and std::clog are exceptions to some degree). If you are using streams by multiple threads you have to synchronize them. If you synchronize them then you do not need synchronization of pword since this is must be addressed by stream owner. More and more think this question suffers from XY problem.

Yes, given @Artyer's answer, the problem is with pword() itself. However, no, this is not an XY problem.

Artyer implicitly assumes that your solution makes sense. I still think thread synchronization in custom manipulator doesn't add up. And I didn't wrote this is xy problem. I've wrote question suffers form it. You are asking to fix your solution, but we do not know what actual problem is. From my perspective this is wrong solution which can't be fixed.

Saying a problem can't be fixed is an acceptable answer.

Your right, the non-atomic read of the pointer at void *p = b.pword( index ); would not be thread-safe with respect to the assignment at b.pword( index ) = p;.
You could try to fix this by using a std::atomic_ref<void*>(b.pword(index));, but you run into the problem that pword() itself isn't thread-safe.
Also, the result of pword() can be invalidated by any operation in the stream, so b.pword(index) = p can be invalid if any operation on the stream is called in any other thread concurrently.
You have to lock around pword(). And you have to use the same lock for all operations on the stream.
It might be easier to just use a map:
my_obj* get_obj_for( std::ios_base &b ) {
    static std::unordered_map<std::ios_base*, my_obj> map;
    static std::shared_mutex m;
    {
        std::shared_lock _(m);
        auto it = map.find(&b);
        if (it != map.end()) return &it->second;
    }
    {
        std::unique_lock _(m);
        auto [ it, inserted ] = map.try_emplace(&b);
        if (inserted) {
            b.register_callback([](ios_base::event e, ios_base& b, int) {
                if (e != ios_base::event::erase_event) return;
                map.erase(&b);
            }, 0);
        }
        return &it->second;
    }
}


Also consider a redesign of what you want to do. You can instead wrap a stream in another stream that contains the my_obj, and use the wrapped stream instead, like std::osyncstream.

Use of std::atomic_ref is a good idea that I didn't think of. I was trying to avoid always locking the lock by using double-checked locking. However, you are right in that pword() itself is not thread-safe, specifically, the void* to which atomic_ref refers will have moved if the underlying array is resized. So I think that means I can't avoid always locking the lock. I did consider deriving a class from ostream instead; perhaps I'll reconsider it.

BTW: the map in your example should be global and map entries deleted upon an ios_base::erase_event received by a callback registered via register_callback().

For me this solution looks like memory leak which can't be detected by tools. Imagine program which writes lots of files and creates stream for that frequently. Each instance of stream will create new entry in map. In bad luck scenario same address will be assigned to stream after old one has been disposed, leading to magic interaction between streams which lifetime do not overlap.

@MarekR Yeah that's why I wrote that note but apparently we can erase the element when the lifetime of the stream ends

Do keep in mind that this will break horribly if you move assign the stream or attempt to swap it. The registered callback will be moved (or swapped) along with the rest of the ios members, but the my_obj will remain associated with the old address. => This will leak the my_obj until the end of the program and if you're unlucky might result in it accidentially being reused in an unrelated stream that happend to be constructed at the same address. godbolt example

The lambda should also handle the copyfmt_event.

I just realized I've been thinking about this all wrong. The iword & pword arrays are part of the stream object. If you are using a single value I obtained from xalloc(), what you should do is call pword(I) immediately to allocate the array. After that, assuming you use only I, the array will never get resized and the returned reference will never become invalid.
